# Simple Oracle (sqlplus) constraint issue... need to ALTER and add variable >0

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, sqlplus

I'm trying to add this into my Oracle database (in SQL*Plus) but how do i make the constraint? i tried check but it wasn't working. Here's what i got though:

-- Add a new attribute years of experience to table Tech_personnel, and enforce
it to be a positive value (i.e., > 0).

my solution:

```
ALTER TABLE Tech_personnel ADD years_of_experience NUMBER(30);

ALTER TABLE Tech_personnel ADD CONSTRAINT non_neg
CHECK(years_of_experience > 0);
```

Comment: This seems quite reasonable. When you say "wasnt working", what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

What, exactly, is not working?

```
SQL> create table tech_personnel( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE Tech_personnel ADD years_of_experience NUMBER(30);

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE Tech_personnel ADD CONSTRAINT non_neg CHECK(years_of_experience > 0);

Table altered.

SQL> insert into tech_personnel values( 1, -1 );
insert into tech_personnel values( 1, -1 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.NON_NEG) violated


SQL> insert into tech_personnel values( 1, null );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tech_personnel values( 1, 1 );

1 row created.
```

Perhaps you also want to ensure that the `YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE` is not NULL?